# AJAX loaded JQuery datepicker only working after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I got a pretty odd question.
I created a field with a datepicker assigned.

This field is being loaded by an AJAX call into a div.

In summarry this is working already.. But there's a catch.
It only works if I set an alert code before I initiate the datepicker.

When I remove the alert. It simply stops working.

The init code is within another function:

```
alert('kut');
$("#mini_calendar").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "now",
    constrainInput: false,
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
    }
});
```

I hope someone knows what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

Thanks a million.

The solution is :

```
    interval = setInterval(function(){ 
        if($("#mini_calendar").length > 0) {
            $("#mini_calendar").datepicker({
                defaultDate: "now",
                constrainInput: false,
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                }
            });
            clearInterval( interval );
        }
    }, 300);
```

Edit:

I am calling these on Ajax success :

```
    ///######## IN CASE OF SUCCESS
    success: function (response) {
        if (response != '') {
            $("[@targetDiv]").html(response);
            DateNav_CalendarInit(DisplayType);
        }
        else {
            alert('error! Something went wrong during the obtaining of data!');
        }
    }
```

**The "DateNav_CalendarInit()" calls the initialisation code**

Comment: Make sure you initiate it after field has loaded.

Comment: Is the mini_calendar id element is dynamically generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the alert you are trying to capture DOM element before it actually exists.

You should wait for the *Document Ready* event:

Example:

```
$(function(){
    // .. your code here ..
}
```

...or simply put your javascript code at the bottom of the  tag (or at least after *#mini_calendar" element).

Comment: I don't actually understand what you mean with that I should be waiting for the Document Ready event since it is generated by an AJAX call.

Comment: Sorry. I overlooked that. But the case is the same: You are trying to capture an element **before** it actually exists.

Of course. If you want to alter element created after an Ajax call completion, relying on Document Ready event will also not work. That's because the event you need to listen for is the actual object creation.

In summary: you can append the code you shown just after creating that element (in the Ajax success callback), call a function containing it instead, or trigger some user defined event to listen for.

Comment: this was the solution together with an interval!! This has been a great idea!!

Comment: No. You did it wrong!!! Relying on an interval will fail again when the network were slow enough. Read my previous comment: I wrote this answer thinking the #mini_calendar element were already on document's html. Using timeout will fail sometimes and using timeout an detecting when works (now I saw your edit) is simply a botched job. Read my previous comment: you need to do it in the _success_ callback of your Ajax() request **after** creating the calendar element or, at least, after some element triggered just then.

Comment: I am already calling it at success. See my edit(11:29 Amsterdam time)

Comment: What does contain received data by the Ajax() call? **plain** html or it has some script inside which happens to be responsible for the creation (or the assignment of that id) of the #mini_calendar input? Where is placed the *div* having "@targetDiv" attribute defined in the exact moment the success callback is called? Are you sure that there is one **and only one**? ...And, of course: the millon dollar question: Is it already placed into the DOM tree somewhere? (If it isn't, `$("#mini_calendar")` selector won't match it.

Comment: ...It seems to me that you are giving us the code you think is wrong and omitting some other which is actually what is causing the trouble. Otherwise your code **SHOULD** work without the interval patch.

The symptoms you tell are claiming that the #mini_calendar element is not created or, at least are not inserted to the DOM tree anywhere in the moment you tried to pick it by jQuery selector and your interval patch only waits for that to happen. It works, of course, for a provisional patch. But it doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem few days ago i did this by jquery load() function.

```
$('body').on('load change','your container element in which #mini_calendar will load',function(){
    $("#mini_calendar").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "now",
        constrainInput: false,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        }
    });
});
```

don't forget to replace container element selector. otherwise code will not work

if not this than you can set interval that will check if the $('mini_calendar') exists or not in an element.